# Add whitespace after comma

Tags: php, arrays, string, function

I'm having some trouble figuring this out.

I have the following CSV string

```
hello world, hello             world, hello
```

The middle value has excess whitespaces. I'm trimming that using

```
preg_replace('/( )+/', ' ', $string)
```

The function is excellent but it removes the whitespaces after the commas as well. It becomes..

`hello world,hello world,hello`

I want to preserve 1 whitespace after commas like so

`hello world, hello world, hello`

How can I do this?

EDIT:

Using `preg_replace('/(?<!,) {2,}/', ' ', $string);` as suggested, works but I ran into another issue.. When I use more than 1 whitespace after a comma it return 2 whitespaces after the comma.

so

```
hello world,             hello world,hello
```

returns

```
hello world,  hello world, hello
```

As a solution I create an array from the CSV string and used `implode()`

```
$string = "hello world,   hello        world,hello";
$val = preg_replace('/( )+/', ' ', $string);
$val_arr = str_getcsv($val); //create array
$result = implode(', ', $val_arr); //add comma and space between array elements
return $result; // Return the value
```

Now I get `hello world, hello world, hello` It also ensures a whitespace after comma if missing.

It seems to work, not sure if there is better way. Feedbacks are welcomed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will match 2 or more spaces together and replace with a singular space. It won't match a space after a comma.

```
preg_replace('/(?<!,) {2,}/', ' ', $string);
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?2ttvh)

Comment: Thanks! It works but I ran into another issue, please see my edit

Comment: If you get rid of the check for a comma, the regex will accomplish what you want -- preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', $string);

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me.

```
$string = "hello world,   hello        world,hello";
$parts = explode(",", $string);
$result = implode(', ', $parts);
echo $result; // Return the value
//returns hello world, hello world, hello
```

Explode only at the comma, and all the extra white space is removed. 
Then implode with a comma space.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the + quantifier, which matches 1 or more whitespaces, use the {2, } quantifier, which will match just 2 or more whitespaces...", hello" won't match that.

Comment: Thanks! It works but I ran into another issue, please see my edit

Comment: @CyberJunkie: That wasn't the recommendation here. The recommendation here was to simply use `/ {2,}/` (without the `(?<!,)`). That should solve all your issues.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new with regex